# How to convert this WHILE LOOP to FOR LOOP?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

```java
package scannerConsole;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingInputChallenge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (counter <= 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter number #" + counter + ":");
            String nextNum = sc.nextLine();

            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(nextNum);
                counter++;
                sum += num;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Enter number #" + counter + ":");
        String nextNum = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(nextNum);
            sum += num;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
```